# How to save data in multiple files on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a bot in python which copy some texts from a webpage. In every run it grab 10k+ texts. so i want to save those texts in different files. every file will keep 100+ texts.

How can i do this in python?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck at? We only help with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. Please [edit] your question to include those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't care what the file names are, you could write each batch of messages to a new temp file, thus:

```
import tempfile

texts = some_function_grabbing_text()

while texts:
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
        fp.write(texts)
    texts = some_function_grabbing_text()
```